# Aligning NoIr images and RPI RGB images

Tags: raspicam, image

I was wondering if given a picture from a RPI NoIr camera and a RPI RGB camera, how can the two images be aligned. From what I understand the NoIR camera when used with the blue filter stores near IR values in the Red band. So how could the RGB image and the NoIR image be aligned?

Comment: there is software available that can overlay two images ... what does that have to do with a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: can it overlay images based on just the Near IR band and RGB bands? I just asked here as I am using a RPI camera and raspberry pi

Comment: image manipulation programs have no knowledge of what the picture shows